# Laravel Form Update can't get the right value

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

so i make `laravel` form for update

**Index.blade**

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="formrow row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="divlabel col-sm-2">
      <label>Kode Program Studi:</label>
      <span class="required">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="divinput col-sm-8">
      <select id="id" data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control populate placeholder" title="kode program studi harus diisi" name='id' required data-plugin-selecTwo>
        <option value="">-PILIH NAMA USER-</option>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
          <option class="form-control" value = '{{$user->id}}'>{{$user->id.' | '.$user->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        <label class="error" for="id"></label>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  {!! Form::open(['url' => 'master/hakakses/'.$user->id,'method' => 'PATCH','class'=>'update']) !!}
  <!-- {!! Form::model($user,['route'=>['master.hakakses.update', $user->id],'method' => 'PATCH','class'=>'update']) !!} -->


  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="divlabel col-sm-2">
    <label>Kode Program Studi:</label>
    <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divinput col-sm-8">
    <select id="role" data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control populate placeholder" title="kode program studi harus diisi" name='role_id' required data-plugin-selecTwo>
      <option value="">-PILIH HAK AKSES-</option>
      @foreach ($roles as $role)
        <option class="form-control" value = '{{$role->id}}'>{{$role->id.' | '.$role->role_akses.' | '.$role->role_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
      <label class="error" for="role"></label>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-50">
    <input type="submit" value="Ubah" name = 'simpan' class = 'btn btn-primary'>
  <td><a href="{{ url('master/hakakses')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Kembali</a></td>
</div>
</div>

  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller :**

```
public function index()
    {
        $data=new HakAkses;

        $users= $data->ListUser();
        $roles= $data->ListRole();
        return view ('Master.HakAkses.index',compact ('users','roles'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

return $id;

    }
```

**Model:**

```
public static function ListUser()
    {
      $table = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users"));
      return $table;
    }
    public static function ListRole()
    {
      $table = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM m_role"));
      return $table;
    }
```

The problem is I can't get the value of `{{$role->id}}` when I try to return `$id` , the value is the latest input of `id` in the database. I think the problem is in the `FORM`:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'master/hakakses/'.$user->id,'method' => 'PATCH','class'=>'update']) !!}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: show your route file

Comment: i use resource route, i think the route is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem is that you're passing here:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'master/hakakses/'.$user->id,'method' => 'PATCH','class'=>'update']) !!}
```

the `$user->id` but you want to get in your controller `{{$role->id}}`

So the solvation is in your controller to:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // $id is a user's id

    $roleId = $request->input('role_id');
}
```

Comment: no the problem is i cant get the id value from dropdown. $roleId = $request->input('role_id'); wont help

Comment: i type return $id; so than i can test what value the $id get

Comment: but `$request->input('role_id')` is a value from the dropdown. Can you paste   your routing file

Comment: my routing is only resource route]

Comment: Ok, maybe I don't understand you... you're getting same error, you're not getting inside controller method, or you're just getting null on the value. Could you dump it (`dd($id)`);